# SQL SUM hours by week across number of years

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sum

I have a table in a SQL database that holds information about the hours worked by employees across a number of years. Each employee can have more than one record for a specific date and each employees start date can be different.

I am trying to sum the weekly hours of each employee based on their first week.
So if the employee started on the 17/04/2018 any hours logged in this week would be considered week 1 for this employee and the following week would be week two etc.
For another employee week one could start in a different day/month/year etc.

My data includes the following fields:

Sequence_ID: relates to an individual employee

Date_European: relates to each date an employee has logged hours with the minimum of this being the first date the employee started in the company

Hours: The amount of hours logged

I also have a year field in the data which is the year of the Date_European column.

The below is what I have attempted but I know it isn't even close to the format I need.

```
select 
    Sequence_ID
    ,DATEPART(week,Date_European) AS Week
    ,DATEPART(year,Date_European) AS Year
    ,SUM([Hours]) AS Weekly_Hours
from [AB_DCU_IP_2018].[dbo].[mytable]
group by 
    Sequence_ID
    ,DATEPART(week,Date_European)
    ,DATEPART(year,Date_European)
order by 
    Sequence_ID
    ,DATEPART(week,Date_European)
    ,DATEPART(year,Date_European)
```

I tried to create the 'Week' field. From the above code it just gives me what week of a particular year a date relates to. I then added the 'Year' column to distinguish between different years, but again this only gives me what particular year that is.

Is there any way to create a 'Week' field in the format I am looking for? (Week of earliest date and surrounding dates would be week 1).

I was attempting to use the rank and partition by function by couldn't get this to work properly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been searching for a solution for hours.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: 
How to create the initial table

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(Sequence_ID   VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL ,Date_European DATE NOT NULL ,Hours NUMERIC(5,1) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO mytable(Sequence_ID,Date_European,Hours) VALUES ('da6Wrw','09/05/2016',7.3);
INSERT INTO mytable(Sequence_ID,Date_European,Hours) VALUES ('da6Wrw','09/06/2016',7.3);
INSERT INTO mytable(Sequence_ID,Date_European,Hours) VALUES ('da6Wrw','09/07/2016',7.3);
INSERT INTO mytable(Sequence_ID,Date_European,Hours) VALUES ('da6Wrw','09/08/2016',7.3);
INSERT INTO mytable(Sequence_ID,Date_European,Hours) VALUES ('da6Wrw','09/09/2016',7.3);
INSERT INTO mytable(Sequence_ID,Date_European,Hours) VALUES ('da6Wrw','09/12/2016',7.3);
INSERT INTO mytable(Sequence_ID,Date_European,Hours) VALUES ('da6Wrw','09/13/2016',7.3);
INSERT INTO mytable(Sequence_ID,Date_European,Hours) VALUES ('da6Wrw','09/14/2016',7.3);
INSERT INTO mytable(Sequence_ID,Date_European,Hours) VALUES ('da6Wrw','09/15/2016',7.3);
INSERT INTO mytable(Sequence_ID,Date_European,Hours) VALUES ('da6Wrw','09/16/2016',7.3);
INSERT INTO mytable(Sequence_ID,Date_European,Hours) VALUES ('da6Wrw','09/19/2016',7.3);
INSERT INTO mytable(Sequence_ID,Date_European,Hours) VALUES ('da6Wrw','09/20/2016',7.3);
INSERT INTO mytable(Sequence_ID,Date_European,Hours) VALUES ('da6Wrw','09/21/2016',7.3);
INSERT INTO mytable(Sequence_ID,Date_European,Hours) VALUES ('da6Wrw','09/22/2016',7.3);
INSERT INTO mytable(Sequence_ID,Date_European,Hours) VALUES ('da6Wrw','09/23/2016',7.3);
INSERT INTO mytable(Sequence_ID,Date_European,Hours) VALUES ('da6Wrw','09/26/2016',7.3);
INSERT INTO mytable(Sequence_ID,Date_European,Hours) VALUES ('da6Wrw','09/27/2016',7.3);
INSERT INTO mytable(Sequence_ID,Date_European,Hours) VALUES ('da6Wrw','09/28/2016',7.3);
INSERT INTO mytable(Sequence_ID,Date_European,Hours) VALUES ('da6Wrw','09/29/2016',7.3);
INSERT INTO mytable(Sequence_ID,Date_European,Hours) VALUES ('da6Wrw','09/30/2016',7.3);
```

What I want as the desired outcome:

```
| Sequence_ID | Date_European | DATEPART(week,Date_European) | Hours | Desired_OutCome_Week |
| da6Wrw      | 05/09/2016    |                           37 |   7.3 |                    1 |
| da6Wrw      | 06/09/2016    |                           37 |   7.3 |                    1 |
| da6Wrw      | 07/09/2016    |                           37 |   7.3 |                    1 |
| da6Wrw      | 08/09/2016    |                           37 |   7.3 |                    1 |
| da6Wrw      | 09/09/2016    |                           37 |   7.3 |                    1 |
| da6Wrw      | 12/09/2016    |                           38 |   7.3 |                    2 |
| da6Wrw      | 13/09/2016    |                           38 |   7.3 |                    2 |
| da6Wrw      | 14/09/2016    |                           38 |   7.3 |                    2 |
| da6Wrw      | 15/09/2016    |                           38 |   7.3 |                    2 |
| da6Wrw      | 16/09/2016    |                           38 |   7.3 |                    2 |
| da6Wrw      | 19/09/2016    |                           39 |   7.3 |                    3 |
| da6Wrw      | 20/09/2016    |                           39 |   7.3 |                    3 |
| da6Wrw      | 21/09/2016    |                           39 |   7.3 |                    3 |
| da6Wrw      | 22/09/2016    |                           39 |   7.3 |                    3 |
| da6Wrw      | 23/09/2016    |                           39 |   7.3 |                    3 |
| da6Wrw      | 26/09/2016    |                           40 |   7.3 |                    4 |
| da6Wrw      | 27/09/2016    |                           40 |   7.3 |                    4 |
| da6Wrw      | 28/09/2016    |                           40 |   7.3 |                    4 |
| da6Wrw      | 29/09/2016    |                           40 |   7.3 |                    4 |
| da6Wrw      | 30/09/2016    |                           40 |   7.3 |                    4 |
```

Comment: Sure this is possible. Unfortunately it isn't clear what you want though. What would really help is posting the table definition, sample data and desired output. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/ Maybe this is as simple as using ROW_NUMBER?

Comment: does the 'first week the employee works' run for 7  days always, or could it be partial, running to a fixed week start date?

Comment: Where is your startDate for each employee held?  What you need to do is calculate the 'week start date' for the week that each employee in your report started, then you are grouping by DATEDIFF(day, EmployeeStartDate, WorkDate) /7

Comment: @Sean - I have added a google sheet of the table as it stands now and the format I want the table in. I didn't use the link you provided as I thought google sheets could be faster, The link has been attached in the question. I think a row_number is the right track but I can't seem to figure it out myself.

Comment: @ Cato - The first week the employee works may not run for 7 days if they start mid week. For example if an employee starts on the 17/07/2018 ideally week 1 would be considered anything from the 15th - 21st. I also have a field that has the start_date of the employee which is the minimum of the European_date

Comment: Faster for you yes, but then for anybody to work with your data we have to go download your spreadsheet, create a table in sql server, then import your data. Creating sample data that is consumable for others means we can spend our time working on your problem, not setting it up.

Comment: @Sean - Apologies updated now with relevant code and desired output for a smaller sample size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found an easier way to calculate the week number of the employee that uses the DENSE_Rank function.

I have included this below incase anyone as similar issues. I have commented out the DATEPART sections as I was only using these columns as a check to ensure it was working correctly:

```
select 
     Sequence_ID
    ,Date_European
    --,DATEPART(week,Date_European) AS Week
    --,DATEPART(year,Date_European) AS Year
    ,DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Sequence_ID ORDER BY DATEPART(year,Date_European), DATEPART(week,Date_European) asc) AS EmployeeWeekNumber
    ,Hours
from [AB_DCU_IP_2018].[dbo].[All_IPower_HR_Assurance_4]
order by 
     Sequence_ID 
    ,Date_European
    --,DATEPART(week,Date_European)
    --,DATEPART(year,Date_European)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Set DateFirst 1

select 
    Sequence_ID,
    (datediff(day , DQ.WeekStarted, Date_European) / 7 + 1) EmployeeWeekNumber
    ,SUM([Hours]) AS Weekly_Hours
--into [AB_DCU_IP_2018].[dbo].[Weekly_Work_Hours_Employee]
from [AB_DCU_IP_2018].[dbo].[All_IPower_HR_Assurance_4]
CROSS APPLY (SELECT DATEADD(day, -1 * (datepart(weekday,start_date) % 7), start_date)  AS WeekStarted   
                                    FROM YourTable 
                                    WHERE <condition  to get the start_date you need>
            ) DQ
group by 
    Sequence_ID,
   (datediff(day , DQ.WeekStarted, Date_European) / 7 + 1)
order by 
    Sequence_ID
    ,DATEPART(week,Date_European)
    ,DATEPART(year,Date_European)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach using the sample data you posted.

```
select mt.Sequence_ID
    , mt.Date_European 
    , DATEPART(week, mt.Date_European) 
    , mt.Hours
    , MyRow.GroupNum
from  mytable mt
join
(
    select WeekNum = DATEPART(week,Date_European) 
        , GroupNum = ROW_NUMBER() over(order by DATEPART(week,Date_European))
    from  mytable
    group by DATEPART(week,Date_European) 

) MyRow on MyRow.WeekNum = DATEPART(week, mt.Date_European)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select *,rn-1 [Employee_week] from (
select *,dense_RANK() over(Partition by Sequence_ID order by iif(weekly_hours=0,0,week) ) [rn] from (
select 
    Sequence_ID
    ,DATEPART(week,Date_European) AS Week
    ,DATEPART(year,Date_European) AS Year
    ,SUM([Hours]) AS Weekly_Hours
--into [AB_DCU_IP_2018].[dbo].[Weekly_Work_Hours_Employee]
from [AB_DCU_IP_2018].[dbo].[All_IPower_HR_Assurance_4]
group by 
    Sequence_ID
    ,DATEPART(week,Date_European)
    ,DATEPART(year,Date_European)
order by 
    Sequence_ID
    ,DATEPART(week,Date_European)
    ,DATEPART(year,Date_European))a)a
    where rn = 2
```

This'll give you the hours each employee worked on their first week, use rn>2 to get the remaining weeks